# SQL CPU trigger on machine memory load

Tags: windows, sql-server-2014, cpu-usage

Does anyone know of a setting or trigger for MS SQL 2014 standard edition that would trigger SQL to start using CPU% when system memory hits over 90% usage. I have a small application that **is not** accessing SQL but does utilize large amounts of memory. When the memory on the system hits 90%+ utilization SQL started showing CPU usage on a continual basis until the toolset is stopped.

I've run multiple analysis such as profiler, queries to see the last statements processed, the connections to the database, etc... Nothing is standing out as being the trigger for SQL to spike. What is even more odd is that this particular machine has both SQL 2014 standard and SQL express on it and both of the versions will trigger the spike (this is not my server but one that I am having to work on).

Comment: So if not servicing the application, what _is_ SQL Server doing at the moment it demands a lot of the CPU?

Comment: @CodeCaster that is the thing, it isn't doing anything. According to the check for last 'x' statements run there is nothing being run. The profiler just some a handful of activities for user check by a service but these are simple actions that don't show much usage. According to the connection check there are only a handful of connections to the master table by **sa** user.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Ed Harper; thank you, I posted the question on there as you recommended.